# MaYin Hachsima in Kedushas Hayom of Rosh Hashuna

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Kedushas Hayom (אתה בחרתנו מכל העמים) of Rosh Hashuna ends off

> ... וטהר לבנו לעבדך באמת, כי אתה אלהים אמת ודברך אמת וקים לעד. ברוך
>   אתה ד' מלך על כל הארץ מקדש מקדש ישראל ויום הזכרון

How does "For You are the true G-d, and Your word is true and endures forever" pair with "King over all the world. Who sanctifies Israel and the Day of Remembrance." (Artscroll-Ashkenaz)?

Comment: Some Nuschaot have ודברך מלכינו אמת וקיים לעד

Comment: A true king has a true domination on his  kingdom.  You are really syrong,  potent and your assertions are not canceled...

Answer (score 1):

It says in [Shabbos 55a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=55&format=pdf) חותמו של הקב"ה אמת, Hashem’s seal is truth.
The King's seal represents the king, when one sees the king's seal he "sees" the king, so when one "sees" אמת one "sees" Hashem.

Comment: Do you have a source that this is the reasoning?